# Separating background-color and opacity?

Tags: css

Is there a way to set the bg color of an element in one place and manipulate its opacity somewhere else?

I know this can be done with transparent PNGs or some stacked DIVs, but i can't use these options (please don't waste time suggesting them).

CSS File A

```
#menubar {
background-color: #036564;
}
```

CSS File B

```
#menubar {
background-color-opacity: 0.5; /* idea 1 */
background-color: rgba(inherit, inherit, inherit, 0.5); /* idea 2 */
}
```

Comment: why you want separate background-color opacity. Where rgba is best solution ever

Comment: @sandeep: The idea here is that he specifies the RGB values in one file, and doesn't want to repeat them in another file with the A value.

Comment: @sandeep: This feature is desirable if you need to set the background opacity of elements dynamically using JavaScript but don't want to have color values in your JavaScript code (where they certainly don't belong).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is currently not possible to specify partial color components and have the rest of the values inherit or cascade in CSS.

If you need to specify a color with an alpha value, you'll have to supply its RGB or HSL values together with the alpha, as the only color values that allow you to specify an alpha component are `rgba()` and `hsla()`. You can't specify the alpha independently of the other color components.

See the [CSS3 Color Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color) for details.

Comment: Thanks, i knew that, but thought there is some tesla magic outhere ;) Thanks for the spelling correction too.

Answer (score 6):

If you use Sass you can define a variable for the rgb color, and then insert it into a rgba color, only specifying the alpha transparency component.

```
$base-color: rgb(200,150,100);

a {
  color: rgba( $base-color, .7 );
}
```

Found on https://robots.thoughtbot.com/controlling-color-with-sass-color-functions

Comment: While the question is not about "Sass" at all, your answer is not at the right place here... Anyway +1 from me for taking the time! Welcome to SO - nice to have you.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way now (very similar to pseudo-code at the end of Stijn's answer):

```
--color: red;
--opacity: 50%;
background: color-mix(in srgb, var(--color) var(--opacity), transparent);
```

[color-mix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix) function takes two colors and for each of them allows adding percentage specifying the amount of each color to mix. In the code above it mixes 50% red with 100% transparent => resulting in 50% red.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually split the two: `background-color` and `opacity`, but in this case `opacity` is applied to the whole element not just the background color.

http://jsfiddle.net/tUHdv/

In the jsfiddle example, notice how the letters in blue square become slightly red.

**NOTE**: This answer was added to clarify that you can use both properties together, except it affects more than the `background-color`.

Comment: thanks, but like you said - opacity applies to the whole element.

Answer (score 0):

## Changing background color and opacity separately

Here is our scenario: We have some element of which we want to change the background color and opacity separately from CSS:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgb(120, 200, 200);
}
```

```html
<div>
  This element has a background color... We want to change the background color and opacity separately, but without changing the opacity of this text.
</div>
```

`opacity: 0.5;` comes to mind, but when we try it, we notice that the element content becomes partly transparent as well. That's not what we want:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: rgb(120, 200, 200);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This element has a background color... We want to change the background color and opacity separately, but without changing the opacity of this text.
</div>
```

### Use a pseudo element

We can insert a pseudo-element into the div, position and size it correctly and then set the background color and opacity on that:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
}

div::before {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; 

  /* The magic is here! */
  background-color: rgb(120, 200, 200);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This element has a background color... We want to change the background color and opacity separately, but without changing the opacity of this text.
</div>
```

Granted, this is only a workaround. But in many situations this can help you achieve what you want.

What we really need is some fancy CSS functions for working with colors so we can do:

```
div {
  --bg: rgb(120,200,200);
  --alpha: 0.5;

  background: rgba(r(--bg), g(--bg), b(--bg), var(--alpha));
}
```

But alas, AFAIK it does not exist (yet).